# Can I print to my printer with PHP and Apache?

Tags: php, windows-7, printing

Is it possible to print in continuous forms (paper) with a dot-matrix printer (EPSON FX-2175)?

For example if I have a table from my mysql database, how would I print that on a continuous form paper with the same headings per page?

I have searched a a lot but can't find an answer for this.

If this is not possible, can you suggest some ways to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: PHP has no native printing support, and you don't mention which OS you're using. You'd need access to the system's printer infrastructure, and/or embedding epson printer control codes into your output, etc... No simple answer for this.

Comment: Now I have that sound stuck in my head.... bzzzzzttt... bzzzzzttt... bzzzzzttt...

Comment: sorry it's windows 7. If that would be the case, how would I be able to print using continuous forms. What are my options? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that you'd be better off avoiding PHP altogether to be honest.

Why not use an ODBC driver from within something like MS Excel.  That's got all of the printing support that you'd ever need.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print something from a web app (although I'm not totally sure that's what you're doing), I would recommend generating a PDF. Check out [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/).